# Remove Sticky Bloatware in Windows 10

Tags: malware-removal, windows-10-v1803, bloatware

Few days back, I installed a software and I do not remember its name on my Windows 10 PC. It showed some error during installation so I immediately removed it.
Since then I am seeing a big square adware (however appears blank always). I looked in `Control Panel > Programs and Features` but there is no strange entry. It is sticky in nature. Doesn't matter if I click on Close button or not. Also clicking on the ad does not take me anywhere.
Here is a GIF of this.
Could someone help me to remove it. I am afraid to browse anything important on my PC.
[image]

Comment: Using Sysinternals Process Explorer you can find out what process this window belongs to and where this Process is located.

Answer (score 1):

Bloatware are very annoying problem in the PCs usually it occurs in the new PCs that takes hard drive space and uses unnecessarily resources. To remove these unwanted applications its better to remove it manually however its time consuming but it doesn't require any third party software. To uninstall manually follow the below steps:
1.Type uninstall in the search bar.
2.Select the program that you want to remove.
3.Click on uninstall

If its not working then try to restore your PC by the backup, You created before the installation of bloatware.